# React Lazy Import does not include CSS files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, react-lazy-load

I have a react app setup with `CRA`.

In my `App.js` I would load my `css` files, components and define my routes.

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import './css/global.css';
import './index.css';
import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';
import ResetPassword from './pages/ResetPassword';
import ResetPasswordConfirm from './pages/ResetPasswordConfirm';

.... 


return (
          <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/reset-password">
                        <ResetPassword intl={intl} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/about-us">
                        ...
                    </Route>
             ....
);
```

Now, I want to implement route-based code splitting with `React.lazy`.

I changed my component imports as follows:

```
const ResetPassword = lazy(() => import('./pages/ResetPassword'));
const ResetPasswordConfirm = lazy(() => import('./pages/ResetPasswordConfirm'));
```

and I updated my return method as follows:

```
return (
      <Router>
                <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                    <Switch>
                         <Route path="/reset-password">
                            <ResetPassword intl={intl} />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/about-us">
                            ...
                        </Route>

);
```

The problem I'm facing is that none of my CSS files which I import above in my `App.js` are being loaded into the components.

I didn't eject my app from `CRA` so I don't have any custom webpack config.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  Did you find a solution that you could share??

Comment: @kuhnflyfish if I remember correctly, the CSS files were being imported, however they weren't imported in the same order as before and as a result the CSS hierarchy changed and different styles were being applied - I ended up explicitly importing the CSS in the components that needed them instead of doing so in App.js - not the best solution but it resolved my issue.

Comment: how to fix this but not like above @Alk